# how to keep track of the current position in std::stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am writing a custom logger where I buffer my log messages in a `std::stringstream` and flush it to a file (`std::ofstream`) whenever the `std::stringstream` is big enough(to save some IO latency) . since`std::stringstream` doesn't have a `.size()` method, I use `seekg` and `tellg` :

```
template <typename T>
MyClass & operator<< (const T& val)
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutexOutput);
    output << val;  //std::stringstream output;
    output.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    if(output.tellg() > 1048576/*1MB*/){
        flushLog();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Problem:
It seems to me that, whenever I invoke this method, it uses `seekg` to start counting the bytes from the beginning all the way to the end and get the size using `tellg`. I came up with this design to save some IO time in the first place, but: isn't this continuous counting impose a larger cost(if the number of calls to this method is high and log messages are small as in most of the cases)?

is there a better way to do this?

And a side question: is `1MB` a good number for buffer size in a normal nowadays computers?

Thank you

Comment: fstream already provides buffering. Have you tested that using a stringstream actually speeds things up? Why not try to customize the size of fstream buffer if you want a larger one? Also, don't use endl and fstreams, use "\n" instead as it won't force flushing.

Comment: I suspect that `stringstream`'s `tellg()` involves some sort of simple pointer arithmetic, so it shouldn't be too expensive. However, as Neil Kirk points out, you should probably just rely on `fstream`'s buffering instead. And whenever you talk about performance, always measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `ostringstream::tellp()` to get the length of the string. Here's an example lifted from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    std::cout << s.tellp() << '\n';
    s << 'h';
    std::cout << s.tellp() << '\n';
    s << "ello, world ";
    std::cout << s.tellp() << '\n';
    s << 3.14 << '\n';
    std::cout << s.tellp() << '\n' << s.str();
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
13
18
hello, world 3.14
```